# Unit Tests for MVC3 AsyncController

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have read a couple of posts on this topic, but neither addresses my issue directly. When you test a synchronous controller method, you can assert that the method is returning the type you expect:

```
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result,typeof(JsonResult));
```

However, when testing async controller methods, I have only been able to assert that the type returned by the AsyncManager is the correct type:

```
var result = controller.AsyncManager.Parameters["articles"];
// Assertions
Assert.IsNotNull(result);
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result,typeof(IEnumerable<NewsArticle>));
```

Seems to me I should be testing the return type of the Completed method which in my case is a JsonResult:

```
public JsonResult GetPublishedNewsArticlesCompleted(IEnumerable<NewsArticle> articles)
{
    return Json(articles, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

But I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. I read a post by [Dino Esposito](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Testing-Asynchronous-Methods-in-ASP-NET-MVC.aspx#1473) in which he said that "the code of xxxCompleted is trivial and probably wouldn't even need a test". I am not buying it. The Completed method and it's return type is what I care most about in this test.

So my question is how do I test that my Completed method is actually giving me back a JsonResult? Or is Dino right and I just shouldn't care?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done with my asynchronous methods is to just test the Async method and not the Completed method. My decision to do this is based on the fact that there is no business logic in the Completed method. All it does is serialize my return object and pass it back as Json or Jsonp if it is cross domain. I didn't write it and most folks will tell you if you don't write it, don't test it.